# Maximization problem of a quadratic and concave function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Suppose that $f(\cdot)$ is a quadratic and concave function such that it has a maximum, $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $y\in(0,+\infty)$. I have to solve a maximization problem that is 
$$\max_{\dfrac{x}{y}}f(x/y)$$
My question is that, since I want to maximize with respect to $x/y$, I will treat this as if $\frac{\partial f(x/y)}{\partial (x/y)}$?

Or do i need to maximize with respect to $x$, then in $y$ and use the Hessian matrix?

Or is it something else? Well it is a composition of functions after all, isn't it? I am a llitle confused...

Comment: just pick any value for $y$ and then solve for $x$

Comment: What you mean when you say ``pick any value for $y$". Should I treat $y$ as a constant?

Comment: well, if $(x,y)$ is a solution, then $(2x,2y)$ is also a solution, right?

Comment: Well I guess so...but I can not understand what is the intuition behind this. How is this going to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $a$ is the point where $f$ is maximal, then, all the couples $(x,y)$ that verify $x/y=a$ are solutions to the optimization problem.

Comment: So, you mean that, by setting the factor $x/y=a$, I can re-state the maximization problem with respect to this $a$ as the control variable?

Comment: Yes, first you find $a$ then $(x,y)$.

Comment: Well, does it matter if $a$ is indepedent of $x$ and $y$? What deos this mean about the optimal $x/y$? Or this is the case, if my problem is well defined, then I need to find such an $a$, that is indepedent of the $x$ and $y$.

Comment: There's some good textbooks about optimization that you can read.  For your problem, if $f(x) = \alpha /2 x^2+\beta x +\gamma$, the optimum is at $a=-\beta/\alpha$.  Therefore, all the couples $(x,y)$ that verify $x=ay$, for $y$ nonnegative, are solutions to the optimization problem.

Comment: Could you please verify these textbooks, about optimization?

Comment: excuse me, but you did not answer to my question, about the textbook that you suggest about optimization. Could you please tell mw ehich one you think is a good one?

Comment: What do you mean by $a/2x^2$? Maybe you mean $\frac{a}{2}x^2$, am I right?$